# Trouble accessing Apple Watch analytics or diagnostics

Tags: xcode, analytics, apple-watch, diagnostics

I am trying to copy diagnostic information for my apple watch app, but cannot seem to find it.

First off, if I go to Settings > Privacy > Analytics, there is an option to turn on iPhone and Watch Analytics. Under Analytics Data, its hard to tell which one is for the Watch app.

Second, I noticed if I go into the Watch Settings using Xcode simulator, then go to Settings and scroll all the way down, there is an option to "Copy Watch Analytics". However, it does not seem to help with debugging an app on my physical watch. When I tried to look for the same "Copy Watch Analytics" option on my physical (not simulator) iPhone, that option did not show up.

Analytics/diagnostics would be very helpful so that a remote user of my app could copy/paste and send me the diagnostic info, so that I can debug their issue. Anyone know a way to do this, or even a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable development for the specific watch in order to be able to access analytics...

This is done in Xcode, the first time you select your iPhone + Watch as target for testing an app, Xcode will complain that the Watch is not enabled for development and ask if it can enable it.

After that, analytics should be available!